# Simulating partitions in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, profiling

I tried to put this to test with the following two queries to simulate partitions in Neo4j (v3.1):

`Q1: MATCH (a:USER { UID:362})-[:FRIEND]->(b) WHERE b.PARTITION=1 RETURN COUNT(b)`
 
`Q2: MATCH (a:USER { UID:362})-[:FRIEND]->(b) WHERE b:P1 RETURN COUNT(b)`

I was hoping (as also discussed [here](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/01/16/neo4j-graph-model-design-labels-versus-indexed-properties.html)) `Q2` would be faster as it would only retrieve the `P1` labels while `Q1` would require retrieving all nodes before filtering them. It turns out that `Q1` is much faster and this became more apparent when I changed the queries to traverse more depth `[:FRIEND*1..5]`.

Edit: There's an index on `UID` and no index on `PARTITION`.

The Query plans are as follows using embedded Neo4j (for some reason doesn't show DBhits).

`Q1`

```
+-------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| Operator          | Estimated Rows | Variables        | Other                       |
+-------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| +ProduceResults   |            191 | COUNT(b)         | COUNT(b)                    |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation |            191 | COUNT(b)         |                             |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| +Filter           |          36341 | anon[33], a, b   | b.PARTITION == {  AUTOINT1} |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |         363412 | anon[33], b -- a | (a)-[:FRIEND]->(b)          |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| +Filter           |         105719 | a                | a.UID == {  AUTOINT0}       |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan  |        1057194 | a                | :USER                       |
+-------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------------+

Total database accesses: ?
```

`Q2`

```
+-------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| Operator          | Estimated Rows | Variables        | Other                            |
+-------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults   |            214 | COUNT(b)         | COUNT(b)                         |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation |            214 | COUNT(b)         |                                  |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| +Filter           |          45909 | anon[33], a, b   | a:USER AND a.UID == {  AUTOINT0} |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |         459085 | anon[33], a -- b | (b)<-[:FRIEND]-(a)               |
| |                 +----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan  |         134181 | b                | :P1                              |
+-------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------------------------+

Total database accesses: ?
```

Any ideas on what the reasoning behind this maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of observations first :

1. It probably doesn't make a difference (given the query plan) but is there a reason you're not writing Q2 as `MATCH (a:USER { UID:362})-[:FRIEND]->(b:P1) RETURN COUNT(b) ?`
2. There's no index or constraint on the user's uid ?

The difference seems to be Q1 and Q2 choose a different entry point. Q1 picks User, Q2 picks P1 which seems to be more efficient. I wouldn't (given the counts) expect a huge difference in query time though. A side-effect of Q1 is that you probably load everything in memory with the scan on User.

If you really want to speed it up, put an index on User(UID). Combined with the P1 label that should really bring down the number of hits.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned: 1. I did try that as well. It returns exactly the same plan. There seem to be no difference. 2. There's an index on the uid. Isn't it strange that Q2 picks that entry point and the uid condition is tested later in the query plan?

Comment: Sure about 2 ? I'm asking because a "NodeByLabelScan" indicates it's sweeping the whole database for all nodes with that label. Can you do a simple query to verify ?

Comment: Oh thanks for this! I just realised I have a legacy index on the UID so I've updated the query to start with `START a=node(362)` and now the `Q2` is slightly faster than `Q1` as expected.